# Isometric tilemap platformer in cocos2d - player jumps?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, tiles, isometric

I've read a lot about building isometric-tile-map based games for iOS using cocos2d (tutorials, examples, etc.). Unfortunately, can't find a proper example of making a classic **platformer** game with isometric tile map. The main thing is - how to make player able to jump, and how to build platforms that can be placed on different level above the ground. I know that this definitely can be achieved with cocos2d, the best example of what I have on my mind is game called "Alone" - http://www.itlgames.com/alone - there are videos and screenshots on the app website, that demonstrates player's ability to jump like in classic platformer game, but the world is presented using isometric tilemap. Author of that game claims that it was made with a help of cocos2d (source: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/games/game/alone-free/374215545). Anyone had seen good open-source example of jumping and platforms on isometric tilemap?

Answer (score 0):

There is an cocos2d/box2d platformer kit available:
http://www.commander-cool.com/ios-2d-platformer-starter-kit.html

Maybe this helps?